# Java Database Error (the abstract schema type is unknown)

Tags: java, database, schema, abstract

I got this error message when I try to create my login menu, before that there is not problem. Don't know since when this problem occur and there is no error notice.

```
[EL Info]: 2018-08-15 19:16:20.494--ServerSession(15826265)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2018-08-15 19:16:20.624--ServerSession(15826265)--file:/C:/Users/Tan Jun Wen/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaProgramming2_Assignment/build/classes/_Investment company databasePU logout successful
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2018-08-15 19:16:20.627--ServerSession(15826265)--Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT a FROM Admin_1 a WHERE a.adminRegisterDate = :adminRegisterDate]. 
[14, 21] The abstract schema type 'Admin_1' is unknown.
[30, 49] The state field path 'a.adminRegisterDate' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Comment: You haven't given enough information to get an answer here.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: My Code for my login form is long and you might be confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Admin_1")
public class Admin {

@Column(name = "ADMIN_REGISTER_DATE")
private Date adminRegisterDate;
......
}
```

And you working with object fields (a.adminRegisterDate) in JPQL, you need use classname "Admin" and not "Admin_1" in query.

SELECT a FROM Admin a WHERE a.adminRegisterDate = :adminRegisterDate

Comment: no Admin_1? Why you try use it? in your code there can be anything. But it should be similar to what I wrote, or in orm.xml on xml-style mapping.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it is the Metadata that I created and added into the JFrame but it is not working so I deleted it.